# How to insert user_id (from DB) and imported data (excel file upload) simultaneously?

Tags: php, database, import, foreach, insert-id

## Table (expected result)

| id | teacher_id | subject | student_id | marks | section_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | math | 200 | 70 | 7 |
| 2 | 23 | math | 201 | 73 | 7 |
| 3 | 23 | math | 202 | 72 | 7 |
| 4 | 23 | math | 203 | 76 | 7 |
| 5 | 23 | math | 204 | 78 | 7 |
| 6 | 23 | math | 205 | 80 | 7 |

I am importing students marks using Simplexlsx.class.php into database in CodeIgniter 3.
I need to import the data from excel uploaded file (contains only rows of student's marks and teacher notes in the excel template), meanwhile I want the student_id (collected from DB) to be inserted into the table simultaneously.

**QUERY to get student_id:**

```
$section = $this->input->post('section-id');
$query_data_student = $this->db->select('student_id')->from('student')->where('section_id', $section)->order_by('name', 'ASC')->get()->result_array();
```

**Looping and inserting from excel upload**

```
foreach( $xlsx->rows() as $r ) {
// Ignore the inital name row of excel file
if ($f == 0){ 
$f++;
continue;}
/**NOT really sure this foreach loop will work**/
foreach($query_data_student as $rows){
   $arr_student_id = $rows['student_id'];
}
        
for( $i=2; $i < $num_cols; $i++ ){ 
   if ($i == 2) $data['marks']         = $r[$i];
   else if ($i == 3)    $data['notes'] = $r[$i];
}
$data['student_id'] = '200'; //have tried to place $arr_student_id;  **//Here is the problem (I want this value [student_id] inserted from student table)**
$data['subject_name']   = $this->input->post('subject');
$data['teacher_id'] = $this->input->post('teacher_id');
$this->studentMarking_model->save($data);
}
```

Using the above code I get the following table in my DB:

## Table (current result)

| id | teacher_id | subject | student_id | marks | section_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | math | 200 | 70 | 7 |
| 2 | 23 | math | 200 | 73 | 7 |
| 3 | 23 | math | 200 | 72 | 7 |
| 4 | 23 | math | 200 | 76 | 7 |
| 5 | 23 | math | 200 | 78 | 7 |
| 6 | 23 | math | 200 | 80 | 7 |

I don't really cope with array data handling.
Many thanks for any kind help.

Comment: What is your actual CSV import data supposed to look like here?

Comment: I am importing student's marks and teacher notes. Basically, I have columns: Number, student_name, marks_1, marks_2, notes in the excel template. I had done successfully importing by only taking marks_1 and notes as to insert using the code. But I failed to insert student_id taken from student table in my DB.

Comment: So you need to correlate the student_name from your CSV data, with the student ID from your database. How do you expect that to work - when you fetch _only_ the student IDs from the database? Say you got a set of IDs now, 11, 47, 93 - how do you tell, which one belongs to which student name? [...]

Comment: [...] You need to fetch _both_ values from the database table, and then stick them into an array - using the student name as key, and the ID as value. That part should happen _before_ your loop over the CSV data, instead of inside, as you currently attempted. And with `$arr_student_id = $rows['student_id'];` you were _overwriting_ the value of that variable in every loop iteration to begin with.

Comment: In fact, I order (order_by("name", "ASC") in my query) the student name, so I will get set of student_id array sequence fixed, because name is set firmly to student_id. [...]

Comment: _"so I will get set of student_id array sequence fixed"_ - and? How does that help you now, to be able to associate the student name with the _correct_ ID? That could only make sense, if the student names in your CSV always came in the exact same order, and there are no "gaps" either (meaning, every CSV would have to update the whole range of students each time, performing only partial updates for specific students, would not be possible.)

Comment: My next question is then how can I simply insert from array student_id 200, 201, 202, 203,204... and marks from imported csv data.

Comment: Exactly. Teacher, who should upload the marks, should always put the marks based on sorted A-Z students name. This scenario is for uploading marks of each different classes.

Comment: Ugh, that really sounds quite very error-prone. But either way, if you want to do it like this - then you still need to fix the issue, that you are currently only overwriting a variable, instead of actually adding the IDs into an array, first of all. Once you done that, you just need to use your loop index, to access the correct array item.

Comment: I have tried ```
foreach($query_data_student as $key => $rows){
   $data['student_id'] = $r[$rows];
}```, this output error illegal offset ..(something, integer)..

Comment: "sounds quite very error-prone.", can you portray how error-prone situation will probably happen? Since I am not yet really good in handling array, would you please suggest code lines. Many Thanks.

Comment: `$data['student_id'] = $r[$rows];` still makes no sense - that would still be overwriting the _same_ entry in $data every time.

Comment: Error-prone in terms of human error. What if one of those teachers ever removed a line from the CSV (maybe a student dropped out?), or changed their order? If you already _have_ the student name in one of the columns, then there is really _no need_ to process this by the order the CSV data is in.

Comment: In terms of simplicity, academic and students affairs as well as the teachers will always be aware of student numbers and composition. To hndle the situation, so I should prompt the teacher with the students list to which he/she wants to upload the marks.

Comment: Select both student_id and student_name in your query, and then inside the first foreach, do `$arr_student_id[$rows['student_name']] = $rows['student_id'];` Then you can use `$data['student_id'] = $arr_student_id[/*student name from CSV row goes here*/];` in the second foreach, to directly access the ID, that belongs to the student name. (And with that, the order of the records on the CSV should not matter any more.)

Comment: I see. Now, I can figure out how it should go. I'll try to implement it on my code.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing what @CBroe suggest, I solve the problem.
This is my first `foreach:`

`foreach($query_data_student as $rows){  $arr_student_id[$rows['student_matrix']] = $rows['student_id']; /*I select student's metric numbers instead of students' name (this to avoid , just in case, there are exactly same student's names. Indeed, I found it during my school age).*/  }`

Then I iterate through for loop:

`for( $i=2; $i < $num_cols; $i++ ){ if ($i == 2)        $data['student_id']  = $arr_student_id[$r[$i]]; //here I get the CSV column of metric numbers after modifying the template else if($i == 3)    $data['marks']   =  $r[$i]; else if ($i == 4)   $data['notes'] =    $r[$i]; }`

Thanks @cbroe for your extraordinary help.